# How discount different values each time in monthly payment using Braintree

Tags: javascript, php, payment, braintree, recurring-billing

I am using recurring payment from Braintree but it looks like they only allow to fix the bonus amount to subtract from each month payment.

```
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/recurring-billing/plans#add-ons-and-discounts
```

However the bonus is different from each user and each month for each user. 
So do you have any idea to customize this ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I work for Braintree.</sub>

You will need to create your custom add-ons and discounts in the Control Panel before they can be applied to your users' subscriptions. After they are created, you can update users' add-ons and discounts as needed using [Braintree_Subscription::Update](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/reference/request/subscription/update).

```
$result = Braintree_Subscription::update('theSubscriptionId', [
    'discounts' => [
        'add' => [
            [
                'inheritedFromId' => 'discountId1',
                'amount' => '7.00'
            ]
        ],
        'update' => [
            [
                'existingId' => 'discountId2',
                'amount' => '15.00'
            ]
    ],
    'remove' => ['discountId3']
    ]
]);
```

Comment: My system allow recurring billing. So I just set default as always recurring billing, then before the date of recurring every month I check user bonus status, if there is new bonus I will use update with numberOfBillingCycles = 1. Else, no need to update. Is this the right way to do in your normal practice ?

Comment: Correct, `numberOfBillingCycles = 1` will limit the bonus applied to one month only. If they have no bonus the next month, no update will be required.

Comment: Thank u for the answer ! :)